# SSL in ESP8266 (Arduino library) - How to handle certificate changes?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm using Arduino library for ESP8266.

As for now in order to make SSL request using `HTTPClient` you need to provide SSL fingerprint.
There's no possibility to accept every certificate at the moment (using library's methods).

I'm wondering how you guys handle it, because the fingerprint can change over time.

Should I get my server's fingerprint over HTTP from another endpoint and then use HTTPS? Or maybe there's a better approach?

Comment: `Should I get my server's fingerprint over HTTP from another endpoint and then use HTTPS` **no**. Since the HTTP connection can be intercepted and arbitrary data can be sent (think: ARP-Spoof to attacker-controller HTTP(S) server), an attacker could give you his own certificate fingerprint, and then you would accept a man-in-the-middled, attacker-controlled HTTPS server connection, since it has the right fingerprint. Also, clarify which library and methods exactly you're using that accept this "Fingerprint". I'm assuming it's the `signatureValue` of the cert.?

Comment: The way you'd usually do this is by two ways: Either add the root-certificate of your domain to the ESPs firmware, and then let it check that the server has a certificate which is properly signed by your root cert. The other way would be to allow only a certain set of certificate fingerprints to be trusted. Also keep in mind that the ESP8266 is resource constrained, so verifying RSA signatures of more than 2048 bit hurts quite a bit (out-of-memory-errors). Consider using ECDSA certs, elliptic-curve crypto is much faster and has shorter keys.

Comment: you have to update the firmware if you don't want to fork the lib or self-defeat the sec

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I'm using method `begin(String url, String httpsFingerprint = "")` from `HTTPClient`: https://links2004.github.io/Arduino/dd/d8d/class_h_t_t_p_client.html#a1145965e2556bffa41fe9df46fe8dc45. `Fingerprint` == `Thumbprint` of the cert. Can you really intercept connection when fingerprint is shared? Couldn't the attacker simply show my certificate? If I add that root-certificate to my ESP the problem would vanish? It would still work after the server's certificate is renewed? How to access those certificates, public and private keys when using AWS Elastic LoadBalancer?

Comment: `Couldn't the attacker simply show my certificate` no, if he redirected you to his TLS server and tried to show you your real server's cert, the TLS handshake wouldn't go through, as he doesn't have the matching private key to your cert, thus would fail in after the `ClientKeyExchange` step of the TLS protocol in deriving the mastersecret. That's the whole point of doing authenticating with a cert. 
`If I add that root-certificate?` Not implemented yet (https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1851) `would still work after certificate is renewed?` Yes if auth by rootcert,no if by fingerprint

Comment: So it seems you could only do the "add the fingerprint" method, and handly an eventual change of the fingerprint yourself (ota updates, backup HTTPS server with never-changing cert which tells you when the other cert has changed, or whatever.)

Comment: It looks like adding root-certificates is implemented already: https://github.com/copercini/esp32-iot-examples/blob/master/ESP32_aws_iot/ESP32_aws_iot.ino

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about security and just want to call some https without replacing fingerprint each time it updates, you can use WiFiClientSecure lib and set client.setInsecure() instead. [Link](https://buger.dread.cz/simple-esp8266-https-client-without-verification-of-certificate-fingerprint.html)